# Mapping Superfund Sites using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography

I am trying to create a map of all Superfund sites in the U.S., and of course it isn't as easy as I thought it would be. I think I have downloaded all the necessary information, but can't figure put how to create this map. I have a basemap, I downloaded the shapefiles from the EPA, but now I am stuck. When I unzip the shapefiles, I have a bunch of excel tables, some of which do contain latitude, longitude information. I just need to do some preliminary mapping for a future project.

Comment: Someone in a class I took was going to do a similar project with mapping Superfund sites, and from what I recall there wasn't a lot of boundary data available. She was going to have to manually digitize boundaries from images, and elected to go another route. What kind of map are you looking to create? At the US scale I'd be thinking they're represented by points. If you got actual shapefiles, there should be shapes and not Excel files. Can you edit your question to include a link to your source? If you have lists of coordinates, converting those to points is already covered many times here.

Comment: Also, what software/version/license level are you using? What do you intend to do with the data in terms of analysis? What is the goal of your project? The answer to these questions could have significant influence on the solutions you're given.

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.2. My project is to examine residential racial segregation around Superfund sites. My intention is to create buffers around Superfund sites and then see how segregated those areas are. The map I am trying to create is simply all the Superfund locations (represented by points) and then create buffers.I downloaded a shapefile and the "single" and "combined" zip file at this location: http://www.epa.gov/envirofw/geo_data.html

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.2. My project is to examine residential racial segregation around Superfund sites. My intention is to create buffers around Superfund sites and then see how segregated those areas are. The map I am trying to create is simply all the Superfund locations (represented by points) and then create buffers.I downloaded a shapefile and the "single" and "combined" zip file at this location: http://www.epa.gov/envirofw/geo_data.html. I am trying to create a map similar to this one: http://superfund.ciesin.columbia.edu/sfmapper/mapviewer.jsf?width=1133&height=706.

Comment: You should **edit** your question using the button in the lower left corner to add additional information rather than posting a long trail of comments. You should be able to add the shapefile to your map with the Add Data button (note it does have to be unzipped first). The csv files are just tables. If they have coordinates they can be added with an XY Event Layer and then exported to a point shapefile. From the wording on that page, not all sites will have coordinates. The single and combined files probably have quite a bit of duplication between them.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad. Would you be able to use the **edit** button to revise it to a more focussed question around precisely where you are currently stuck, please?  At the moment we are unable to tell whether you have successfully added your shapefile to a map or tried Add XY Event Layer successfully/unsuccessfully.  I recommend always trying to place a single question mark somewhere within your question body because that immediately defines the focus of your question.

Comment: I was able to download and add that shapefile with no issue, however... First, there are almost 2.4 *million* records in that dataset. Even before seeing that and without knowing how you planned to address 'segregation' (assuming census data), I figured you'd probably want to narrow your study down a bit. Second, I don't think you have the correct data. I believe FRS facilities are those *reporting* to the EPA - as in any company/site currently required to file a report with them. There should only be around 1,300 actual [Superfund sites](http://www.epa.gov/superfund/sites/npl/index.htm).